# Nested shortcodes in WordPress not working even after adding do_shortcode($content)

Tags: wordpress, nested, shortcode

I'm trying to create custom shortcodes for bootstrap and am running into some difficulty. I have seen numerous articles that called for using do_shortcode($content) in place of just ($content), but can't seem to get it to work.

My code is as follows in my functions.php file:

```
add_shortcode( 'container', 'container' );
add_shortcode( 'onefourth', 'onefourth' );
add_shortcode( 'onethird', 'onethird' );
add_shortcode( 'onehalf', 'onehalf' );
add_shortcode( 'twothirds', 'twothirds' );
add_shortcode( 'threefourths', 'threefourths' );
add_shortcode( 'fullwidth', 'fullwidth' );


function container ( $atts, $content = null ) {
    return '<div class="container"><div class="row">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</div></div>';
}

// COLUMN SUPPORT
// One Fourth
function onefourth ( $atts, $content = null ) {
    return '<div class="col-sm-3">' . $content . '</div>';
}

// One Third
function onethird ( $atts, $content = null ) {
    return '<div class="col-sm-4">' . $content . '</div>';
}

// One Half
function onehalf ( $atts, $content = null ) {
    return '<div class="col-sm-6">' . $content . '</div>';
}

// Two Thirds
function twothirds ( $atts, $content = null ) {
    return '<div class="col-sm-8">' . $content . '</div>';
}

// Three Fourths
function threefourths ( $atts, $content = null ) {
    return '<div class="col-sm-9">' . $content . '</div>';
}

// Full width
function fullwidth ( $atts, $content = null ) {
    return '<div class="col-sm-12">' . $content . '</div>';
}
```

What am I missing? I get the container to output

```
<div class="container">
```

but cannot get any of the columns to output. I simple see, for example,

[onehalf] THE CONTENT [/onehalf].

I've also tried changing 
`return '<div class="col-sm-size">' . $content . '</div>';`

to

`return '<div class="col-sm-size">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</div>';` for each of the column shortcodes, and it still doesn't work...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: are you sure your functions are being called ? and shortcodes are being created , i can see that the code is totally okay and there is no problem , but to me issue seems to be is , thode add_shortcode hooks are not being executed. somehow the functions are not working , what else you have inside your functions.php ? is this file inside theme's folder which you are using currently?